# How to access a shared mailbox via Office365 Rest API?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

We can access the shared mailbox if it is shared with a user by using user's OAuth. Whereas here I want to access a shared mailbox which doesn't have a user via Office 365 Rest API. Is it possible via Rest API? or Can we achieve the same via EWS or Graph APIS?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, do you mean you are trying to access a Mailbox anonymously ?. Or are talking about using something like App only tokens https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service . You should also state what you have tried and if you try something and it doesn't work say what the error was as that will make it clear to anybody looking what your trying to do.